# Confusion related to dynamic programming

Tags: algorithms

I was going through this dynamic programming problem. However, I have a confusion

[image]

[image]

[image]

In the third picture, having the black border, I didn't get how the

For each, we try each string of the k strings B ∈ L, and compute the optimal alignment of B with A[t : j] in time O(n(j − t)) = O(mn).

How it was O(n(j-t)).

Also, I didn't get how come there are $O(m^2)$ values of c(t,j)

Can anyone please explain?

Answer (score 0):

The man idea is that they're trying to build a table containing all possible pairs of $t$ and $j$.  After this is done, they can find an optimal solution from the table.

We know that $t$ and $j$ are both between 1 and $m$, so there are at most $m$ values for $t$ and at most $m$ values for $j$.  In other words, there are at most $O(m)$ values for $t$ and $O(m)$ values for $j$ for a total of $O(m) \cdot O(m)$ combinations of $t$ and $j$, or $O(m^2)$.

As the table is built, we can consider a particular $j$ and $t$.  There are $j-t$ values between $t$ and $j$, so this gives a size of $j-t$ or $O(j-t)$.  This takes time $O(n)$ for each value, so we multiply $O(n)$ by $O(j-t)$ to get $O(n(j-t))$.

I hope this helps to explain things.  You may also want to consider posting this at [Stack Exchange's Computer Science Beta](http://cs.stackexchange.com).  Just remember to wait a little while before posting there, as cross-posting is frowned on.

Let us know if you'd like more explanation.